# What is this <Something>_ in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

What is this little snippet of code "Called" or "Doing" in Vb.net.

Specifically the stuff thats between the <>_.  I understand what the property is doing.  I'm just not sure of the significance of the line above it.

```
<TheApp.DataHandler.ColumnAttributes("BillingClientName")> _
Public Property BillingClientName As String
    Get
        Return _BillingClientName
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _BillingClientName = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Can you point me in the right direction to duplicate this functionality.

Comment: it is an attribute and the `_` is the line continuation symbol. what it is doing is assigning the value "BillingClientName" to a custom attribute called `ColumnAttributes`

Comment: More on code attributes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: Just an FYI, the line continuation symbol isn't needed in most cases in recent versions of the Framework.

Answer (score 2):

By "duplicate it" I take it to mean how to use custom attributes.  Start by defining the Attribute:

```
Public Class FormattedAttribute
    Inherits Attribute

    Private _flag As Boolean = False
    Public Sub New(ByVal b As Boolean)
        _flag = b
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property IsFormatted() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _flag
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

An Attribute is (usually) just a small, simple class which inherits from `Attribute`.  This one will simply store a True/False flag on an Enum:

```
Friend Enum MyEnum
    ... 
   <Formatted(True)> FileSize
   ...
Enum
```

**Note:**  The convention is to define the class appending `Attribute` to the name.  But in usage, that can be dropped.

Attributes are meta-data compiled into your app.  They provide some bit of information about a class, property, method etc.  They dont do anything by themselves.  The target (class, property etc) has no awareness of any attributes attached to it: a `DefaultValue` or `Range` attribute do nothing on their own - they are for something else to read and use.

Next, you need a way to read/get that flag from the `FormattedAttribute`:

```
Friend Shared Function GetFormatFlag(ByVal EnumConstant As [Enum]) As Boolean
    Dim fi As FieldInfo = EnumConstant.GetType().GetField(EnumConstant.ToString())
    Dim attr() As FormattedAttribute= _
        DirectCast( _
            fi.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(FormattedAttribute), False), _
            FormattedAttribute())
    If attr.Length > 0 Then
        Return attr(0).IsFormatted
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

This long version allows that the attribute may or may not exist on the Type you are searching (as is the case where this is actually used).  In code, get it by calling the `GetFormatFlag`:

```
IsFormatted = GetFormatFlag(mi)
```

If you know the attribute is there, there is a slightly easier way:

```
Friend Shared Function GetMyKey() As String
    Dim myAttr As myAttribute

    myAttr = CType(Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(GetType(myClass), _
            GetType(myAttribute)), myAttribute)

    Return myAttr.Key
End Function
```

The short version can be modified to get the `myAttribute` value/key from any class implementing it by passing the Type but that is about as flexible as Attributes are.

They can be used with assemblies, classes, methods and fields, and the way to get them back using `System.Reflection` and will differ a little by Type but is basically the same.

They are not great for embedding data in classes or properties because there is no one size fits all for them: Each attribute requires its own class def and reader method.